# Add strings into .txt file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with records that looks like the following:

```
Aaron,Daniel,,,AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH
```

I need a batch file that can look to the correct comma and insert quotes as well as add a comma to the end of the file.

I have this batch file which successfully adds quotes to the beginning of each line:

```
@echo
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^"%%a >>output.txt
)
```

What I need is for the output to look like:

```
"Aaron,Daniel,,",AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH,
```

Comment: What determines the correct comma?

Comment: Due to the requested output it will always be between the 3rd and 4th comma on every line.

Comment: Is there a chance that you have more one instance of 3 consecutive commas in each line? or it occurs only once in each line?

Comment: Hopefully I'm answering your question, the 3 consecutive commas on each line are blank placeholders for each record and will be consistent throughout the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood from the comment under your question, the 3 consecutive commas occurs only once in each line. For that matter the solution is extraordinary simple:

```
@echo off 
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("input.txt") do (
        set "Line=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo "!Line:,,,=,,",!,
        endlocal
    )
)>"output.txt"
```

It initially starts with delayed expansion off and enables delayed expansion at each iteration of the loop to prevent corrupting lines that contain the `!` character.

Since the `,,,` occurs only once in each line (As I understood) it can be safely replaced by `,,",`

`tokens=*` is only needed if you want to remove the possible leading white spaces from each line, otherwise you can just use "delims=" to read the whole line in to a single token.

Answer (score 1):

If an alternative approach is of interest.

With sample file test.txt:

```
Aaron,Daniel,,,AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH
Bob,Edward,,,AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH
```

Using sed, replace the 4th comma with `",` and add `"` at the beginning (`^`) and `,` at the end (`$`):

```
sed 's/,/",/4' test.txt | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/,/'
```

Returns:

```
"Aaron,Daniel,,",AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH,
"Bob,Edward,,",AARDA,MEDICAL,10,HEH,
```